# Tell Python fabfile to use different Python interpreter?

Tags: python, fabric

Is there a way to tell a Python Fabric script (fabfile.py) to execute using a different version of Python than the default Python?  I have a virtual environment that was built using Python 2.7 and my fabfile has to execute within the context of the venv.  However, I'd like for this fabfile to run using my python3 executable so I can utilize some of Python 3's features.  Can I do anything like what you can do within a Bash script where you can say "#!/bin/bash" thereby specifying the exact Bash executable that should be used to run the script?

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: I don't know how to do it to try and see if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are running it:

```
$ fab ...
```

Try

```
$ which fab
```

to find where it is.  For me it is at `/usr/local/bin/fab`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys

from fabric.main import main

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw?|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(main())
```

So you could edit that or create a copy: `fab3` or a version specific to your env.